# plotting a sympy plot in web2py

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, web2py, sympy

I want to plot a sympy plot in web2py  by writing a web2py function myplot4() and call it using 
http://host:port/app/controller/myplot4.png

This is the demo sympy code for a plot which works in a python shell.

```
from sympy import symbols
from sympy.plotting import plot
x = symbols('x')
p1 = plot(x*x)
p2 = plot(x)
p1.append(p2[0])
p1
```

I found a recipe in http://www.web2pyslices.com/slice/show/1357/matplotlib-howto

This recipe works fine but it imports FigureCanvasAgg and Figure whereas in sympy the import is plot function

Can somebody tell me how to write similar functions for plotting sympy plot in web2py based on this recipe (or otherwise)

```
from matplotlib.backends.backend_agg 
import FigureCanvasAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
def pcolor2d(title='title',xlab='x',ylab='y',
         z=[[1,2,3,4],[2,3,4,5],[3,4,5,6],[4,5,6,7]]):
    fig=Figure()
    fig.set_facecolor('white')
    ax=fig.add_subplot(111)
    if title: ax.set_title(title)
    if xlab: ax.set_xlabel(xlab)
    if ylab: ax.set_ylabel(ylab)
    image=ax.imshow(z)
    image.set_interpolation('bilinear')
    canvas=FigureCanvas(fig)
    stream=cStringIO.StringIO()
    canvas.print_png(stream)
    return stream.getvalue()
```

then try actions like the following:

```
def myplot2():
    response.headers['Content-Type']='image/png'
    return pcolor2dt(z=[[1,2,3,4],[2,3,4,5],[3,4,5,6],[4,5,6,7]])
```

and call them with

http://host:port/app/controller/myplot2.png

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer by experimenting and it is trivial.

```
def plot_sympy():
    from matplotlib.backends.backend_agg import FigureCanvasAgg as FigureCanvas
    from matplotlib.figure import Figure
    import io
    from sympy import symbols
    from sympy.plotting import plot
    x = symbols('x')
    p1 = plot(x*x)
    p2 = plot(x)
    p1.append(p2[0])
    s = io.BytesIO()
    p1.save(s)
    fig=Figure()
    canvas=FigureCanvas(fig)
    canvas.print_tif(s)
    return s.getvalue()
def myplot4():
    response.headers['Content-Type']='image/png'
    return plot_sympy()
```